# Why am I getting an SSLHandshakeException as a JAR when the program works in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, https, jsoup, sslhandshakeexception

I have a Kotlin program that uses jsoup to download data from a certain website. Testing it in IntelliJ IDEA, it works fine. When I produce a JAR artifact, it fails with a `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException`.

I've tested it on multiple JRE installations, on both Windows and Linux, both 1.8 and 10, including the copy that came with IntelliJ, and the JAR fails every time. The site's root certificate is [DigiCert Global Root G2](https://global-root-g2.chain-demos.digicert.com/info/index.html), which seems to be in cacerts for each installation I've tested -- the thumbprints match and everything.

I ran the JAR with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` and it included this near the end of the output; more excerpts available on request.

```
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
        at ...
```

Comment: Try running with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` to get more details/logs.

Comment: @CrazyCoder That's quite a lot of text! I'd be happy to add more details to the question, but I'm not sure which bits are relevant. I'm guessing the 600 lines of "adding as trusted cert..." are mostly irrelevant; I'll start by adding an excerpt that looks promising, then add more if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For IntelliJ-IDEA use the built-in trust certs plugin:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-server-certificates.html

It also has a checkbox that let's you ignore certs.